# How can I return null from React.FC component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I'm confused about ESLint and TypeScript.

I can't return `null` because *ESLint: Use `undefined` instead of `null`.(unicorn/no-null)*

Ok, I don't mind and change `null` to `undefined`. Now I have more errors

*ESLint: Do not use useless `undefined`.(unicorn/no-useless-undefined)* and

*TS2322: Type '({ testId, authType }: PropsWithChildren) => Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FC'.   Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.*

```
const AuthForm: React.FC<Props> = ({ testId = '', authType }) => {
  switch (authType) {
    case 'logIn':
      return <LogIn testId={testId} />;
    case 'changePass':
      return <ChangePass testId={testId} />;
    case 'newPass':
      return <NewPass testId={testId} newPassStatus="resetPass" />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

How to deal with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should turn off the `unicorn/no-null` rule, React components cannot return undefined.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/25546

```
{
  "unicorn/no-null": "off",
}
```